# How do I pause and stop video of omxplayer by using python script?

Tags: video, omxplayer

Currently I am using omxplayer to open videos and audios. It works really well.I can pause the video using p/spacebar and other key bindings. My question is how to stop/pause/fast forward by using python script?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing in NodeJS, the way i handled this was to pipe the keyboard input into omxplayer from the command line.

First make a special FIFO ( first in first out ) file. Then we can use this file to pipe "hotkeys" to omxplayer. Anything we write comes out in the order the file is read. The second command cats the output of this and pipes it into omxplayer.

> mkfifo t
>   cat t | omxplayer --no-osd -b myvideo.mp4 &

Then to pause: ( 'rm t' removes the FIFO file )

> echo p > t
>   rm t

Source: http://subupi.blogspot.nl/2012/10/piping-across-shell-sessions-to-control.html

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example using [rofavadeka's method](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61658/67191):

```
import os

os.system('mkfifo t cat t | omxplayer --no-osd -b myvideo.mp4 &')

def play_pause():
  os.system('echo p > t rm t')
```